# how i can get the data that stored in list

Tags: c#

I want to generate a random number from first list (list of Object) and put it in the second list to get a random connection id to make connection between the original id and the random id how I can get the item from the first list by index and of which type I have to cast it

```
  public class OneHub :Hub
{
    static List<UserId> ConnectedUser = new List<UserId>();
    static List<MessageDetail> CurrentMessage = new List<MessageDetail>();
    static List<ConnectionsId> Connection = new List<ConnectionsId>();


    public void Connect(string id)
    {

        if (ConnectedUser.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
        {
            ConnectedUser.Add(new UserId { ConnectionId = id });

            if (ConnectedUser.Count != 0 || ConnectedUser.Count != 1)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                    int x = r.Next(0,ConnectedUser.Count);
                    (object)ConnectedUser.item[x];

                    Connection.Add(new ConnectionsId {ConnectionId=id,ConnectionId2= })     

   }}}
```

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image. It can't be easily searched, can't be copy/pasted, and is a waste of bandwidth. Copy the relevant code as *text* into your question.

Comment: I don't understand why this is in a loop.  Why would you need a loop if you only want to connect to one person?

Comment: @Hogan I want to get all connection ids from the list to generate random number

Comment: @AbdalrahmanMakahleh if there are 10 items in the list and you are generating a number between one and ten then you only need to do that once... you need to "get" anything.  the expression `.item[x]` gets the random item from the list -- the whole list.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks but .item doesn't work I mean I can't call it

Comment: @AbdalrahmanMakahleh - ok you probably want `ConnectedUser[x]`then but I have no way of knowing without seeing the rest of your code.  Also, I'm not going to answer any more questions unless you edit the question to include the TEXT of your code and not an image.  Do that now.

Comment: @Hogan okay I have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're going to need to make sure that the ConnectedUser that you randomly get is not the same user you are linking to, before you add that connection, or you're going to find further issues.

For `ConnectedUser`, you can get the index by simply using `ConnectedUser[x]`.  (I suggest making your lists plural so it's obvious that they're collections.)

You need to assign that connected user to a new object.
Something like

```
UserID linkedUser = ConnectedUser[x];
```

This way, you can reference `linkedUser.ConnectionId` in your connection addition.

Alternately, you could just use:

```
Connection.Add(new ConnectionsId { ConnectionId = id, ConnectionId2 = ConnectedUser[x].ConnectionId };
```

This random setup, though, does have a strong potential for having several people ending up not linked to anyone.  Additionally, your line that states:

```
if (ConnectedUser.Count != 0 ...
```

is redundant.  You just added a user to that list.  It should never be of size 0.

Comment: thank but I'm checking if the list has one element and that's my first time programming I have a lot of problems

Comment: I think `ConnectedUser.Count > 1` is what makes sense.  Checking for not  0 and not 1 is doing two checks instead of one.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks again :)